# How to integrate tabula-js in an angular 9 app?Is there any other way to select specific parts from the rendered pdf and extract the data in json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, tabula, pdf2json

I tried installing the tabula-js library but since it's a js lib I don't know how to integrate it in angular which works on ts.

Also if not this, then is there any way to select specific parts from a rendered pdf document by coordinates and then use it to extract the data.
I basically need to make a pdf to json extraction webapp.

Answer (score 0):

`tabula-js` is a Node package, so it can't be ran in the browser. To integrate a web application with Tabula, you'll need to expose its functionality through some kind of API.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can extract the pdf text of a certain coordinate (x,y,height,etc) only then?